# ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, fetch

Full error:

> Error: Error serializing `.b` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
> Reason: `object` ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON.
> Please only return JSON serializable data types.

I am trying to call one of my functions that retrieves some data from an API endpoint however when trying to pass this data to props I get an error. I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong as the fetch call works if its within GetStaticProps but I want all my logic for fetch calls to exist within a separate js page to reduce redundancies, however when doing so this error is created.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

let b = WordpressService.getPageByIdTest(50);

return {
    props: {
        b: b,
    }, 
    revalidate: 30     
}
```

}

```
const WordpressService = {
    async getPageByIdTest(id) {
    
        const resIndexPage = await fetch(`${url}pages/${id}`);
        const indexPageData = await resIndexPage.json();

        return indexPageData;
    }
}
```

Comment: `await WordpressService.getPageByIdTest(50);`?

Answer (score 7):

I was going over the latest version of nextjs and I did notice that the demo was odd when I ran it. Specifically, I got this error when running their example:

> Error: Additional keys were returned from `getStaticProps`. Properties
> intended for your component must be nested under the `props` key, e.g.

```
export async function getSortedPostsData() {
  // Instead of the file system,
  // fetch post data from an external API endpoint
  const res = await fetch('..')
  return res.json()
}
```

This is not exactly your issue but assigning the props object via res.json() also caused the same error you are experiencing.

So, for me, using node 15 I changed my api call to:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const url = `https://my-url`
    const result = await fetch(url)
    return { props: {
      result: await result.json()
    }}
}
```

And this solved my problem. So Ivar's comment looks correct - await the result and then in my case I had to also await the json result from node-fetch so that the promises completed properly.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily solved with the package "superjson".
Effective and easy to use.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/superjson

for me, I wanted to convert "QuerySnapshot" from firestore which has timestamps in it.

```
posts = (await getDocs(postQuery)).docs.map((postDoc) => {
  return superjson.stringify(postDoc);
});
```

[image]

picture from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/superjson